# Menu item selection does not change textview background

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I've changed popup theme in my app. But there is a problem. When user clicks on menu item, background of label doesn't change as you can see on image below.

[image: First image - usual state; second image - clicked state]

style:

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
<item name="android:background">@color/primaryDark</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item></style>
```

setting menu

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main);
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: have you given any background to settings TextView ? if yes then remove such background from Settings TextView.

Comment: No. I changed only style I put above. If I remove it selection will be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me.

In style xml file

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:background">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>

    <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">true</item>
</style>
```

In layout xml file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/PopupTheme" >
```